# Get WooCommerce cart subtotal in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've set up some code to tweak a few things in the WooCommerce cart using Javascript fired by a PHP if statement, dependent on the subtotal in the cart. I've successfully used the below code to get the subtotal:

```
global $woocommerce;
$subt = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal;
```

Unfortunately, the cart can also be updated with Ajax, without reloading the page, which means that my calculation is thrown off.

I think I need to update the cart total with Ajax, but the solutions I've looked at online seem more geared towards more complicated solutions and I can't find a way to boil it down to just retrieving the subtotal value.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add look for changes in the cart with Javascript and if there is any then call the PHP function with Ajax. You can read how to do it here: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Let's say that this is your PHP function:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );

function my_action() {
    global $wpdb;

    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

    $whatever += 10;

    echo $whatever;

    wp_die();
}
```

Then this will be your JS script:

```
jQuery( document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function(){
     var data = {
        'action': 'my_action',
        'whatever': ajax_object.we_value
    };
    jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the total price DOM and get text from it, for example:

`document.getElementsByClassName("order-total")["0"].getElementsByClassName("woocommerce-Price-amount amount")["0"].innerText;`

If you need the numbers only, use `replace()` function, like:

`document.getElementsByClassName("order-total")["0"].getElementsByClassName("woocommerce-Price-amount amount")["0"].innerText.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');`

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way for doing this would be:

##### 1. Create an ajax/API method to return the cart total

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_get_cart_total', 'get_cart_total');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_cart_total', 'get_cart_total']);

function get_cart_total()
{
    global $woocommerce;
    echo $woocommerce->cart->get_total('edit');
    wp_die();
}
```

##### 2. Call this ajax method in the frontend

```js
let cartTotal;
jQuery.ajax({
    url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
    method: 'POST',
    async: false,
    data: {
        action: 'get_cart_total',
    },
    success: (response)=>{
        cartTotal = response;
    },
    error: (response)=>{
        alert('Failed');
        console.log('Failed. See logs for details');
    }
});
```

Note that I created it in a synchronous way, just to assign it to the cartTotal (which I was going to need in the following line).